# How to prove this inequality for exp?

Tags: calculus

I want to prove that $e^x\ge 1+x$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

I can't use neither derivative nor logs.

Edit: I SAID I can't use derivatives... and Taylor's theorem use this...

Comment: It would be interesseting to know what you can use, that is: How do you define $\exp$?

Comment: Maybe it couold follow from this definition of an exponential function: $e^{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^{n}$

Comment: @Mykolas Indeed, that definition and Bernoulli's inequality are enough.